# Yarn script fails to execute when building in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: build, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, yarnpkg, azure-pipelines-build-task

I managed to setup Yarn in Angular app and when I run: `yarn install`
it successfully installs all the packages which makes the app run with no issues.

Inside `package.json` I have written some scripts to help me out run the specific task (I want node_modules folder to be inside wwwroot).

```
"scripts": {
    "install-dev": "yarn install --modules-folder ./wwwroot/node_modules",
    "install-ci": "install --modules-folder ./wwwroot/node_modules",
}
```

When I have to install packages locally I use `yarn run install-dev`, which works perfectly.

However, when I need to build the project using Visual Studio Team Services, using ***Yarn Build and Release Tasks by Geek Learning*** I pass in `run install-ci` inside VS Team Services **Arguments** which fails with the following error:
[VS Console.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EK9A3.png)

What I find weird is that it says `Version: 1.1.1001`, but under it writes `yarn run v0.27.5`. It seems like that version `v0.27.5` does not support `--modules-folder` (and anyway why is it running the wrong version?).

Here is how Yarn task is configured in Visual Studio Team Services - [VS Yarn task configuration.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucq5V.png).

I am making sure that I am in the correct branch (`bower-to-yarn`) as well as pointing to the Project Directory - `src/MyApp` where I have `package.json` file. Also, it says that the task should run with `Version: 1.*`.

Any help would be very useful. Thank you!

---

*The reason why I have `"install-ci"` without `yarn` is because inside vsts console yarn gets loaded and does not need to be specified again. The same applies to Arguments field inside Visual Studio Team Services `run install-ci`.*

Comment: Can you give the detail build log by setting `system.debug` = `true` in build Variables Tab? And what's the yarn version did you installed on the build agent machine? And there has 2.*(preview) for yarn task, so what if you use this version of yarn task to build?

Comment: Thank you @Marina-MSFT, but already changed the structure of my folders. Now my entire project is in the root folder. I had many unnecessary subfolders. When I set the msts Yarn task without running any special scripts, it builds with no issues.